# usage of indefinite articles

Tags: articles

I am writing a title and I was wondering whether I can skip the second article just like you would say a pen and pencil.  Can I say, "A cap and tie for Zed," or must it still be "A cap and a tie for Zed?"

Have been searching the net and books for some answers but have been unsuccessful.  Would appreciate a quick response from some Grammar Genius!  Need clarification here to finish up my work.

Thanks ya.

Comment: You may skip the second article.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can "re-use" an article for a second noun in such a construction, just like you can re-use any adjective. "I gave a cap and tie to Zed." "I gave blue caps and ties to everyone." Etc.

Even if that weren't true, there is much more leeway in titles than in text that is supposed to be complete sentences. It would, for example, be perfectly acceptable to write a title of, "Cap and Tie for Zed". But in a complete sentence, you need an article (or an adjective that can take the place of an article).